# cacheput-annotation-not-updating-cache-hazelcast-cache in spring boot

Tags: hazelcast

After calling updatePerson method, when I call getpersons method records are not updated plz help, what is missing...

```
 // getting all person in this way
 @Cacheable(cacheNames="person")
public List<person> getpersons(){
    System.out.println("In getpersons Component..");
    try{
        persons = personRepo.findAll();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return persons;
}

 //want to update single record in this way, db is updating successfully but //not cache
@CachePut(key="#personNum")
        public Person updatePerson(Person person,String personNum){
    System.out.println("In updatePerson Component..");
    Person person1= personRepo.save(person);
    System.out.println(person1);
    return person1;
}
```

Please help with this problem, Cache must be updated as expected.

Comment: Can you please share hazelcast related code i.e. how `personRepo.save(person);` and `personRepo.findAll();` touches hazelcast?

Comment: I am using spring jparepository so save and findAll are api method.

Answer (score 0):

You’re updating a record with a key called personNum and in the get method you’re requesting with a null key, again a key based get. This is why you cannot see the update. Spring doesnt allow you to read whole cache through @Cacheable annotation. You need to access cache directly or throught spring-hazelcast-data module.

Comment: Actually there are multiple records I am fetching so using cacheable to cache all records(working fine, my first hit goes to db then subsequent call fetch records from cache). Should I update cache without key ? could you make understand by example, I am new in cache :)